# Navigating back to Home Fragment with NavController Stucked at newly launched fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller

Am having a an Activity with a NavHostFragment which hold my Apps main navigation graph of which its HomeFragment in the NavGraph also has a NavHostFragment in it and a TabLayout, now the problem am having here is when i navigate out of the HomeFragment which has NavHostFragment in am on unable to comeback use the back botton its get stucked at the newly launched Fragment